# Traversing and changing values in matrix

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with traversing a matrix. I'm a coding novice so I apologize if this is a basic question.

I need to write a function that, given a NxM grid, returns a grid with all cells in a column or row originally containing a star turned into stars. Values which have been transformed into stars do not affect their rows and columns. You should do this in-place – by changing the original grid, not by creating a new one. Your function should return the grid.

This is what I have so far:

```
function starOutGrid(grid) {

    grid = [R][C];
    let i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < R; i++) 
    { 
        for (j = 0; j < C; j++) 
        { 
            if ( row[i] == "*" || col[j] == "*" ) 
            { 
                mat[i][j] = "*"; 
                return mat[i][j]
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This sounds like homework. We'd be happy to lead you in the right direction, but what have you attempted so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: where did R,C,row,mat come from?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. Following [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), can you zero-in on the "specific problems with your existing implementation"?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is completely wrong. What are `R` and `C`? And `row` and `col`?
There are a lot of problem in your code (and in your question, I'm not sure to had understood everything).

You can try something like:

```
function starOutGrid(grid, rowSize, colSize) {
    for (let i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i) {
        for (let j = 0; j < colSize; ++j) {
            if (grid[i][j] === '*') {
                // Make col and row all of '*'
                for (let k = 0; k < rowSize; ++k)
                    grid[k][j] = '*';
                for (let z = 0; j < colSize; ++j)
                    grid[i][z] = '*';
                i++;
                j++;
            }  
        }  
    }
    return grid;
}
```

In practice:

- cycle on each element of the matrix
- if you find a "*", then transfor all the elements on the same row (`i`) in '*', then do the same for each element in the same column (`j`).
- go to the next column and row (because all the elements in this col and row are already stars '*'

I hope I understand the text of the problem.